# How to invoke argument passing in thread

Tags: java

I want to do a Java program with a thread with parameters `y` and `n`

- `y` --> starts a thread
- `n` --> stop the thread
- `y` again --> It will start processing from the previous state where I stopped the thread

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way of pausing a thread is to implement a variable for telling the thread to pause, and to implement "wait" and "resume" with functions lock() and notify().

More details here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html
(look for: "What should I use instead of Thread.suspend and Thread.resume?")